# Q/KDB+ Create new column through a query

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery

I have data in a table where there are "Buys" and "Sells" alongside the Quantity. I want query so that if it equals a "SELL" i multiply the Quantity column to negative. so far i am just selecting the data and taking from a certain timeframe. Nothing complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `update` functionality along with the `where` clause you can edit a column in a table using certain filters. In this case the filter is `where side=SELL`.

If you add a backtick to the table name in the update statement this will update the table in place.

```
q)tab:([]time:10:00 12:00 13:00 14:00;side:`BUY`SELL`BUY`SELL;qty:300 400 300 500)
q)tab
time  side qty
--------------
10:00 BUY  300
12:00 SELL 400
13:00 BUY  300
14:00 SELL 500
q)update qty:neg qty from tab where side=`SELL
time  side qty
---------------
10:00 BUY  300
12:00 SELL -400
13:00 BUY  300
14:00 SELL -500
```

Updating in place:

```
q)update qty:neg qty from `tab where side=`SELL
`tab
q)tab
time  side qty
---------------
10:00 BUY  300
12:00 SELL -400
13:00 BUY  300
14:00 SELL -500
```